# Need to know if I'm using AJAX correctly to delete row(s)

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make an AJAX call in order to delete table rows generated via Flask/HTML. I thought I could add another request method in Flask and use it specifically with AJAX, but I suppose not? I'm using sqlite, if that helps at all.

AJAX:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    var rowsToRemove = [];
    $(".checkitem:checked").each(function() {
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        rowsToRemove.push(rowIndex+1);
});

delete_ajax = $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url : "/home",
    data : rowsToRemove,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
});

delete_ajax.done(function(responseObject, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if(responseObject.status == 200) {
        reloadTable();
    }
});

delete_ajax.error(function() {
  alert("Unable to delete row(s). Please try again.");
});
```

Flask:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")

        name = name[0].upper() + name[1:]

        month = request.form.get("month")

        date = request.form.get("date")

        data = db.execute("INSERT INTO birthdays(name, month, day) VALUES (:name, :month, :date)", name=name, month=month, date=date)

        length = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM birthdays")

        db.execute("UPDATE birthdays SET row_id = :rowID", rowID=length[0]["COUNT(name)"])

        return redirect("/")

    if request.method == "DELETE":

        length = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM birthdays").fetchone()[0]

        index = list(range(1, length+1))

        data_to_delete = request.json.get("data")

        rowsToRemove = db.execute("DELETE FROM birthdays WHERE row_id IN :data", data=data_to_delete)

        db.execute("UPDATE birthdays SET row_id=:rowID", rowID=index)

        return {"status":200}

    else:

        rows = db.execute("SELECT name, month, day FROM birthdays")

        return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here and how I can get what I want to work properly.

Comment: check your browser console see if you have any error

Comment: @Swati I get these:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:56
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
changes.js:3 initial number of items checked: 0
changes.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: delete_ajax.error is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (changes.js:102)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
/home:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)